# Open chrome new tab in Selenium automated chrome

Tags: python, selenium, webbrowser-control

I'm creating a automated online banking balance check for my mother that's not really good at computer, I've stuck at the part that i want to open pdf file that already automated dowload in local pc then open in **selenium automated chrome** , is there anyway to do that , Thank you.

with normal webbrowser.open, it only open the chrome not the **selenium automated chrome**

```
import webbrowser
file_ = 'C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\MASTERCARD PLATINUM'+month_year+".pdf"
webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://www.google.com")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle a PDF document in Selenium test automation, we can use a java `library` called `PDFBox`

```
public void verifyContentInPDf() {
    //specify the url of the pdf file
    String url ="http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf";
    driver.get(url);
    try {
        String pdfContent = readPdfContent(url);
        Assert.assertTrue(pdfContent.contains("The Pdf995 Suite offers the following features"));
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

***For Python you can follow this*** [link](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/09/pypdf2-library-for-working-with-pdf-files-in-python/)

Comment: Is there a way to do it in Python ？

Comment: Yes, there is way, you can see this https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/

Comment: I also updated the answer

Comment: Is that work for you ?

Comment: I haven't try it out but Thank you !